# Why is webrat.log always conflicting when you merge using git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, webrat

I am just very confused by this conflicting thing. I do want to put webrat.log into my .gitignore so that I don't need to merge it every time. Yet I notice from Michael Hartl's Rails 3 tutorial book that webrat is a testing utility gem. So I really don't know whether I can ignore it.

Please help me, a newbie rails programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, you should ignore every *.log file. They'll be deleted, modified, whatever every single time you run anything, and unless you *really* need them to be under control, they shouldn't be.

(And you basically never need them under source control.)

Comment: Thanks @Dave, just one more thing, what do you mean by source control?

Comment: @adam_0628 ... git. Git is an [SCCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System).

Comment: @adam_0628 No problem :) Here's something else--go back and [accept some answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), it's how stackoverflow works, and lets future visitors know what the "best" answers were for a question. (You can skip this one or wait to see if anyone else has additional input--I'm just one guy ;)

Comment: Gotcha! I've ticked your answer since you already solved my concern.